# ispunct() does not detect single quote character

Tags: c++

I am trying to read in a file and remove all punctuation from the file. I've been using ispunct() to iterate through the string and check if the character is a punctuation but it doesn't seem to catch all the punctuations. I wanted to know if i am doing something wrong. Here is my code:

### 2.txt

How are you?

I'm fine, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

//removes punctuation, numbers, and extra spaces
void removeNonAlph(string &tmp)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < tmp.length(); i++)
     {
         if (ispunct(tmp[i]))
             tmp.erase(i--, 1);
         else if (isdigit(tmp[i]))
             tmp.erase(i--, 1);
         else if ((tmp[i] == ' ') && (tmp[i+1]) == ' ')
             tmp.erase(i--, 1);
     }
 }

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{

    ifstream file("2.txt");
    string tmp;
    string words[500];

    while (getline(file, tmp))
    {
        removeNonAlph(tmp);
        toLower(tmp);
        cout << tmp << endl;
    }

    file.close();
}
```

### Output:

how are you

i'm fine thanks

Comment: Fyi, `std::string::erase` returns an iterator for a reason, and you should use that feature. Better still, use something like `std::remove_if` to do the enumeration for you.

Comment: [`ispunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) has locale specific behaviour... perhaps your locale is set to something "unusual"?  It's also possible that your editor has placed a non-ASCII single-quote in your input text file.

Comment: By the way, it's dangerous to call `ispunct` (`isdigit` etc.) without casting the character constant to `unsigned char` first, as signed characters with negative values may crash your application.  `ispunct(static_cast<unsigned char>(tmp[i]))`.  (That's because the implementation of these predicates often returns a boolean value from an array it indexes using the character value.  Having to check for negative indices would slow down implementations, so it's left to the caller to consider that safety issue.  Nasty stuff.  Some implementations uses unsigned chars anyway, but for portability...)

Comment: @TonyDelroy I think my text editor is definitely the problem. Downloaded the text files from my class website and it worked fine for that .txt file but not from the .txt file i made on my own. And thank you, i didn't know that! I'll implement the cast :)

Comment: What's "toLower"? https://ideone.com/5HK0bR not reproducible here.

Answer (score 4):

(Comments moved to answer for easy discovery by future readers)

Beware editors putting non-ASCII quotes into your text files.  Many editors generate "smart quotes" that look nicer by showing the right and left quote differently, rendered using different non-ASCII character codes.  `ispunct` normally only works for ASCII input.